# Ports aren't sending output

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, atmega, atmega32

I don't understand why, despite the calling the function and despite setting and clearing the bits appropriately neither does the PWM work nor does the LED blink when the switch is pressed/unpressed. I am using an *Atmega 328 microcontroller* for this project.
These are the following codes used.

main.c

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include "gpio.h"
#include "DoorLock_ver_2.h"
#include "adc.h"
#include "PWM.h"
int is_locked;
int main(void)
//copy this main() to proteus
{

    //unsigned int bit:1;
    // Insert code
      GPIOConfig(PD1,OUTPUT);
      GPIOConfig(PD2,OUTPUT);
      GPIOConfig(PD3, INPUT);
      GPIOConfig(PD4, INPUT);
      GPIOConfig(PD5, OUTPUT);
      GPIOConfig(PD6,OUTPUT);
      int s=0,r=0;
    while(1)
    {
        s=SpeedAssess();
        r=RemoteCtrl();
        if(s==1)
        {
            PWM(1);//JUST TESTING for locking
            is_locked=1;
        }
        else {
            if(r==1){
                PWM(1);//for locking
                AutomaticWindow(1);
                is_locked = 1;
            }
            else{
                //for unlocking
                PWM(0);
                AutomaticWindow(0);
                is_locked = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

DoorLock_ver_2.c

```
#include<avr/io.h>
#include<util/delay.h>
#include "gpio.h"
#include "adc.h"
#include "PWM.h"
#include "DoorLock_ver_2.h"


short int SpeedAssess(){
    //check if speed is greater than 20kmph and sends signal to lock the door
    
    if (GPIOPinRead(PD4)){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
short int RemoteCtrl(){
    //on pressing the button, lock the door
    if (GPIOPinRead(PD3)){
        //AutomaticWindow(0);
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        //AutomaticWindow(1);
        return 1;
    }
}
void AutomaticWindow(short int f){

    //closes window automatically when vehicle is locked(lock button is pressed on remote)
    if(f==1)
    {
        GPIOPinWrite(PD2,HIGH);
        GPIOPinWrite(PD1,HIGH);
    }
    else
    {
        GPIOPinWrite(PD2,LOW);
        GPIOPinWrite(PD1,LOW);

    }
}
```

I made an GPIO api for the Atmega328, coz they insisted us on doing it, I couldn't make the API work for all the ports, so it is specific to port D of the microcontroller

gpio.c

```
#ifndef GPIO_C_INCLUDED
#define GPIO_C_INCLUDED
#include "GPIO.h"
#include<stdint.h>
#include<avr/io.h>
#include<util/delay.h>
#define INPUT 0
#define OUTPUT 1
#define HIGH 1
#define LOW 0
int PIN,MODE,State;


/******************************************************************************
    * Name: GPIOConfig (pin, mode)
    * Description: Configures the mode of the pin as INPUT/PULLUP or OUTPUT
    * Arguments: pin and mode
    * Returns: None
    ******************************************************************************/
int GPIOConfig(PIN,MODE)
{
    if(MODE==OUTPUT)
    {
        SET_BIT(DDRD,PIN);  //output configuration
    }
    else if(MODE==INPUT)
    {
        CLR_BIT(DDRD,PIN);  //input configuration
        SET_BIT(PORTD,PIN); //pullup configuration
    }
}


/******************************************************************************
* Name:GPIOPinRead(pin)
* Description: The function returns the state (0 or 1) of the input pin to be read.
* Arguments: pin
* Returns: 0 or 1
******************************************************************************/
int GPIOPinRead(PIN)
{
    uint8_t PIN_READ=0x00; // 00000000
    PIN_READ=PIND;

    if (PIN_READ & (1<<PIN)) // (00000100)& (00000100) //Pooling
    {
        return LOW;
        //CLR_BIT(PORTD,PD7);// LED off change pd7 to pin //here change it to returning value
    }
    else
    {
        return HIGH;
        //SET_BIT(PORTD,PD7); // LED on change pd7 to pin //here change it to returning value
    }
}

/******************************************************************************
* Name:GPIOPinWrite(pin, state)
* Description:  The function is used to write LOW or HIGH state to GPIO pin.
* Arguments: pin and state
* Returns: none
******************************************************************************/
int GPIOPinWrite(PIN,State)
{
    if(State==HIGH)
    {
        SET_BIT(PORTD,PIN);
    }
    else if(State==LOW)
    {
        CLR_BIT(PORTD,PIN);
    }

}


/******************************************************************************
* Internal functions
******************************************************************************/
/******************************************************************************
* Name:
* Description:
******************************************************************************/
/******************************************************************************
*****************************************************************************
* End of File
******************************************************************************/


#endif // GPIO_C_INCLUDED
```

Also I am using the proteus tool for the simulation setup. This is the only state it achieves after I play the simulation.
[Final state of the simulation tool, no change even if the switch is clicked. click on link to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLzDL.png)

Where am I going wrong? Please help.

Comment: One thing to check.  since a mechanical switch is being used, the value read from the switch needs to be `debounced`

Comment: I tried a code with the exact same logic as that I have shown in the question and it was working then. But now it isn't. So there maybe somethings missing. Anyhoo, how do I debounce the switch? Could you please send a link or a code for the same.

Comment: Do not over-engineer debouncing. Commonly it is sufficient to sample buttons once every 20ms to 100ms. Implementing a cyclical sampler is basic stuff, I'm sure you can do it yourself. Only in very specific cases or with very bad buttons, you need to do more.

Comment: one way to debounce a digital input (which can be either 0 or 1)   input discrete bit.  2) delay amount of time you decide is long enough (a few CPU clock cycles) 3) input discrete bit and compare to the first input of that discrete.  If same, use that value.  Other wise, repeat 2 then repeat 3. until two successive reads of the discrete match

Comment: What is `PWM(1)`?

Comment: @AterLux PWM() is a function I made which is used to send PWM signals of a certain period and duty cycle, based on an argument. I removed that code segment from the question because I wanted the issue of the inactive LEDs to be fixed first.

Comment: @AnirudhG the issue is your code gets stuck somewhere. And probably in one of the functions you have removed.

Comment: I don't understand how is it possible, I did make it a point that all the header files are called so that the necessary functions are available to use and can be called easily. I don't understand how is my code stuck. Can you help me out @AterLux?